# Facing ReactNativeBlobUtil request error in React Native

Tags: react-native, pdf, blob, react-native-pdf

I was facing issue in **React Native** when using `react-native-pdf` to display pdf in App

**logs displayed in console:**

> Error: ReactNativeBlobUtil request error:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Use of own trust manager but none
> definedjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Use of own trust manager but
> none defined]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Open Your code and simply use **trustAllCerts** prop and set its **value false**

**as shown below :**

```
<Pdf
                    trustAllCerts={false}
                      source={{
                        uri: pdfUrl,
                        cache: true,
                      }}
                      onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
                        console.log(`Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
                      }}
                      onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
                        console.log(`Current page: ${page}`);
                      }}
                      onError={error => {
                        console.log(error);
                      }}
                      onPressLink={uri => {
                        console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`);
                      }}
                      style={styles.pdf}
                    />
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks. Another point to keep in mind is, if you enclose this <Pdf/> in <SafeAreaView/> it doesn't work!!